# Version control of a script that should also be in PATH

Tags: git, version-control

I've written a script that I'd like to be able to call on demand (I want it to either be aliased or in PATH). I also want to version control this script through git (or something else, if there's a better solution for this).

In the past, I've put aliases in my .bashrc to the directory of the script and managed it through git from there. Once I believe I was copying the script/binary to /usr/bin/ after every update (I know, that's terrible).

Is there a reliable way to do this? I don't want to go to the point of packaging and distributing this package, I just want version control for myself and to make it publicly available.

Comment: Copying to `/usr/local/bin` is considerably less terrible than `/usr/bin`. :)

Comment: By "publicly available", what exactly do you mean? Installing scripts in `$HOME/bin` and putting that location in your PATH is a common idiom. That said, packaging may be a lot easier than you think/expect; if your script is written in Python, the setuptools "entrypoint" mechanism will build and install wrappers for you.

Comment: Personally, I package scripts I write with [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) -- installing something packaged with Nix installs its dependencies (and ensures that when the script is invoked, those dependencies are in its PATH), but *doesn't* put those dependencies in the PATH unless requested or overwrite other versions of those same tools.